# Forecast in Jupyter Notebook using Weka

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, wrapper, weka, forecast

I would like to predict data using the python-weka-wrapper in Jupyter Notebook, however, I just get the error but not the given prediction. This is a sample of my data:

```
@relation data_new3

@attribute pos_x numeric
@attribute pos_y numeric
@attribute angle numeric
@attribute vel numeric
@attribute vel_x numeric
@attribute vel_y numeric

@data
414049364,21773560,75.06043,16.775027,15.827037,-5.559355
414049656,21773926,43.232657,4.452031,3.258594,-3.033504
414049938,21774287,43.836066,4.347145,4.300749,-0.633426
414050204,21774638,44.704315,4.157368,3.119995,2.747606
```

This is my current code:

```
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
import weka.core.converters as conv
from weka.classifiers import Evaluation, Classifier
from weka.core.classes import Random
import weka.plot.classifiers as plcls
df = conv.load_any_file("data_new3.arff")
df.class_is_last()

cls = Classifier(classname="weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression", options=["-C","-S","1"])
evl = Evaluation(df)
evl.crossvalidate_model(cls, df, 10, Random(1))
plcls.plot_classifier_errors(evl.predictions, absolute=False, wait=True)
```

I would like to get n number of predictions (forecast).
Below the result of the above code. However, I would like data not error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvzF2.png)

What I'm doing wrong? I cannot find the right function in https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.html

UPDATE:

evl.predictions content:

```
[NUM: 2.341519980578598 -0.46169578717854165 1.0,
 NUM: 0.0324593108656498 -1.250148004408402 1.0,
 NUM: 1.0894596695042125 -0.19638227888390247 1.0,
 NUM: 2.2415137801101532 0.21523000008892268 1.0,
 NUM: 0.8403094260947848 1.4159336571192398 1.0,
 NUM: -0.6246802557143522 0.02694804349266633 1.0,
 NUM: -1.1291083174467442 -0.9771784825188661 1.0,
 NUM: 1.9865123314290711 0.0020180962164886296 1.0,
 NUM: -1.4171054579203468 -0.1185322656565404 1.0,
 NUM: 1.701392413210111 -0.31173498990392545 1.0,
 NUM: 0.9142204697441169 -0.46289838829034125 1.0,
 NUM: 2.2371544887471027 0.26863408847202663 1.0,
 NUM: 1.0104945457853498 0.08266907560209802 1.0,
 NUM: -2.1844092184524277 0.2537549599419435 1.0,
 NUM: -1.64486932964462 -0.0757717380165559 1.0,
 NUM: -0.8833185855520697 0.272053514894651 1.0,
 NUM: 2.023258402624002 0.20075652151535905 1.0,
 NUM: -0.09766261800428815 -0.13010619249325828 1.0,
 NUM: 0.008614470166021827 -2.0206928075313044 1.0,
 NUM: -0.3746145438554381 0.2627094869476423 1.0,
 NUM: 0.321292162562831 -0.39300510611246864 1.0,
 NUM: -0.8603272578575111 -0.24401632088301994 1.0,
 NUM: 1.2917808082313293 0.27398191955035145 1.0,
 NUM: 2.5069928462982736 -0.28666784299093706 1.0,
 NUM: 0.5342954034915244 0.023908866474812385 1.0,
 NUM: -0.8199944215138957 -0.35662294870599 1.0,
 NUM: 1.5190967129296846 -0.494692957136067 1.0,
 NUM: 2.1750768892884005 0.17687020938865317 1.0,
 NUM: -1.3129196874730458 -0.4337196896722162 1.0,
 NUM: 0.9085960948511023 -1.0273595147173182 1.0,
 NUM: -1.790840080776049 -0.7976173866791214 1.0,
 NUM: 0.6226362259069361 0.8034413426921674 1.0,
 NUM: -1.6641718286913476 0.1441503225123597 1.0,
 NUM: 0.9671958169480396 0.4460301975123002 1.0,
 NUM: -0.0762479157090975 -0.014214109052772983 1.0,
 NUM: 0.1274295194870555 -0.7136733953120711 1.0,
```

Comment: first you could check what you have in `evl.predictions` - you could use at least `print()` for this. And maybe you should use normal `scatter_plot` or `line_plot` to display it. [weka.plot.dataset](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.plot.html#module-weka.plot.dataset)

Comment: I've updated the answer with the content of evl.predictions. you me use normal display command using the same variable evl.predictions?

Comment: first I would try `plcls.line_plot(evl.predictions)`  (see in link in previous comment). But if it doesn't like `evl.predictions` then I  comment and to see what data it nees. Maybe you will have to convert it to `dataset` - [Create dataset manually](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper/examples.html#create-dataset-manually)

Comment: I don't know how evl.predictions will change if I plot it in a different way. Do you think the problem is the dataset? I've used it in Weka and it worked. Is the code right?

Comment: `plot` doesn't change values in `evl.predictions` - it may only display it in different way then you expect.

Comment: I understand that plot doesn't change the 'evl.predictions', however, as I've shown, the values from that variable are not similar to the dataset, so, I'm wondering if there is a problem with the forecast algorithm or anything wrong in the code.

Comment: I get this error: 'module 'weka.plot.classifiers' has no attribute 'line_plot''

Comment: see link in my first comment - `weka.plot.dataset.line_plot`

Comment: I could make it run using as data the original dataset. How can I avoid using no_class()? since the attributes don't require classification only forecasting

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) is for collecting statistics, not for building a model that you can use for making predictions. In your case, 10-fold CV generates (and throws away) 10 models during the evaluation process and collects the predictions from each of the train/test pairs (which you can access via the `predictions` property).

Instead of evaluating your classifier and plotting the errors:

```py
evl = Evaluation(df)
evl.crossvalidate_model(cls, df, 10, Random(1))
plcls.plot_classifier_errors(evl.predictions, absolute=False, wait=True)
```

Train the classifier and use it. Something like this (for a numeric class):

```py
from weka.core.dataset import Instances
train, test = Instances.train_test_split(df, 80.0)  # 80/20 train/test split
cls.build_classifier(train)
for i in range(test.num_instances):
    print(cls.classify_instance(test.get_instance(i)))
```

Some pointers:

- [code example](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/examples.html#build-classifier-on-dataset-output-predictions)
- [Classifier documentation](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.html#weka.classifiers.Classifier)